# How not to display a text in popup when it's not filled in Leaflet?

Tags: dictionary, popup, leaflet

I do not want to display the variable in the pop up if the variable is not available. For example, sometime "university", or "title" or "city" or "state" is not always filled. So I want to find a way to not display the missing variable in the pop up when it is the case. Thank you for the help.

```
var a = addressPoints[i];
        var title = a[2];
        var univ = a[3];
        var city = a[4];
        var state = a[5];

       var marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { title: title } );

        var content = "<ul><li>title: "+title+"</li> <li>University: "+ univ +"  <li>City: " + direct +"<li></li></ul>";                
        marker.bindPopup(content);
        markers.addLayer(marker);
    }
```

Comment: in case **title** is null, so you don't want to show the respective **li**?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rewrite of Muzzafar's answer without using the jQuery library. Instead simply use Leaflet's own `create` method contained in the `DomUtil` class:

```
create( <String> tagName, <String> className, <HTMLElement> container? )
```

> Creates an element with tagName, sets the className, and optionally appends it to container element.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#domutil-create

```js
var map = new L.Map('leaflet', {
    'center': [0, 0],
    'zoom': 0,
    'layers': [
        new L.TileLayer('//{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            'attribution': '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
        })
    ]
});

// Create ul
var content = L.DomUtil.create('ul', 'my-list');

var title = 'My Title';

var university = 'My University';

// Check if title is set
if (title != '') {

    // Is set so create li and append to content ul
    var titleItem = L.DomUtil.create('li', 'my-list-item', content);

    // Add text to li node
    titleItem.textContent = 'Title: ' + title;
}

// Check if university is set
if (university != '') {

    // Is set so create li and append to content ul
    var universityItem = L.DomUtil.create('li', 'my-list-item', content);

    // Add text to li node
    universityItem.textContent = 'University: ' + university;
}

// Create marker
var marker = new L.Marker([0,0]).addTo(map);

// Bind popup with content
marker.bindPopup(content);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body, #leaflet {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Leaflet 0.7.7</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//npmcdn.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="leaflet"></div>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//npmcdn.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Long time no see! :-)

Comment: Sorry @A.Alfredo i'm having a hard time understanding what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure what, but you must be doing something wrong. I added a working snippet to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate your `content` variable like this

```
var title = a[2];
var univ = a[3];
var city = a[4];
var state = a[5];

//create an empty ul
var content = $('<ul/>');

//check if title is not null
if(title!=''){//in the case, append li to ul
    $(content).append("<li>title: "+title+"</li>");    
}
if(univ!=''){
    $(content).append("<li>University: "+ univ +"</li>");  
}
```

Comment: Note that you need to add jQuery.

Comment: the same can be done without jquery, even the same work can be done using simple javascript

Comment: Absolutely, it would have been preferable to show code without using jQuery.

Comment: replace your `content` variable line with what I've mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @muzaffar I have the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" So it means that I need jquery

Comment: yeah exactly, can't you include the jquery in your project?

Comment: No he shouldn't. Why pull in another library for something as simple as this? Leaflet even has it's own DOM manipulation utilities included.

Comment: I'll throw in an answer, gimme a couple of minutes.